# how to launch a clojure repl in a project with a only a pom.xml file

Tags: clojure

In projects where there is a mix of java and clojure code such as, https://github.com/mikera/clisk

how would one launch a clojure repl to test out the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [clojure maven plugin](https://github.com/talios/clojure-maven-plugin) to the pom. Then `mvn compile` and the `mvn clojure:repl`. The project's Java compiled classes will be available in the classpath, so you can import them from the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a script that launched nRepl or the regular repl. It would need to be aware of the right things to put in the classpath. There might be a maven plugin that does this, although I haven't heard of one.

Another option would be to bake things like launching a repl directly in your application.

You could also program the application to reload code and/or run unit tests. I have a Clojure+Java application. I have menu options that appear when launched with certain system properties. The menu options reset the state of the application and reload all of the Clojure code. There's also a menu option that does that and then runs the unit tests, which puts up a JOptionPane message box to display results.